# Google SEO - Migrating website from a sub-directory of another website to its own domain name

Tags: seo, googlebot

At the present moment I have a website hosted on `example.com/myWebsite`, where `example.com` hosts in its root directory a different website. I have the domain `example.net`, which redirects to `example.com/myWebsite`. The point, however, that right now when somebody accesses example.net they are redirected to `example.com/myWebsite` and consequently to `example.com/myWebsite/dirA`, `example.com/myWebsite/dirB` etc..

I am now thinking about upgrading my account so that `example.net` no longer redirects to `example.com` - I was however wondering, however, since Google shows results searches in terms of `example.com/myWebsite`, how would this affect my rankings?

Answer (score 2):

When you move content from a sub-directory to its own domain, you typically lose Google rankings for up to a year until Google starts to trust the domain.

Google has launched features in Webmaster Tools to help change the domain name of an entire site, but they don't support moving a portion of a site.

UPDATE:

Since this answer was originally written the [Google change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) now supports subdomain moves:

> Use the Change of address tool when your site move entails a domain or subdomain change, such as changing from `http://fish.example-petstore.com` to `http://example.com` or `http://example-petstore.com`.

Comment: Any site move will result in some fluctuations for some time, as the signals propagate, but you shouldn't lose rankings for a year (for most sites it's somewhere between days and a month or so, depending on the size).

Comment: That is better than last time I tried it a few years ago.  I lost rankings for 8 months when I moved a site from a subdomain of my main site onto its own domain name.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, there woud be 301 redirects from `example.com/myWebsite/` URLs to `example.net` pages after you have upgraded. Ask your host about this.

If the 301s are not possible, the next best way is to use meta-refresh redirects without delays (while keeping the old pages there for this purpose).

For example, on the head section of `example.com/myWebsite/dirA`, there should be

```
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=http://example.net/dirA" />
```

Google [recognizes these as 301 redirects](http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/google-and-yahoo-treat-undelayed-meta-refresh-as-301-redirect/), so the **ranking benefits are transferred to the `example.net` pages**.

It's important that you do these from page to page, in an unique manner - not redirecting every page to `example.net` root.

Comment: Hi Arttu, this is qute different from what Stephen answered, coul dyou please clarify on whether benefits are transferred or not? :)

Comment: Hi Dario, if you use meta-refresh or regular 301 redirects as I suggested, most (not necessarily all) ranking benefits **are transferred**. 301 is a way to tell search engines about mere URL and domain changes. This is common SEO knowledge, not anything controversial. :)

Comment: Your search engine trust is more _site-specific_ than _domain-specific_. As long as the site stays the same, the domain change doesn't reset the trust (if you have the 301s/meta-refreshes in place).